# AWS lambda functions future scheduling

Tags: amazon-web-services, events, scheduled-tasks, aws-lambda

I have a requirement to send email and SMS based on some conditions to users, i want to publish a message to AWS (Any service) with time and message at the time of user creation, is there any way to call a lambda function based on my scheduled time along with message?

Comment: Your description is confusing. Are you saying that when a User is created within your application, you wish to define a future time when a Lambda function should execute, with information about the User being passed to the Lambda function? If this is not accurate, please Edit your question to clarify your requirements.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by sending a message to any service? Also where do you create users?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you are saying is that you want to store a message and a 'time to send' someplace and then when that time comes, send out that message via SMS and/or SES, correct?

Lots of ways to accomplish it, but one way would be to store your messages into the database of your choice (perhaps dynamodb), and have a lambda function that gets called periodically (every minute or whatever frequency you determine) to find messages that are ready to send.

In this scenario you could use cloudwatch events to call the lambda function at the interval you decide (but no more frequent than once per minute).

Possible enhancement (especially if you have a  huge number events) would be to have the lambda function not actually process the sms/ses sends - but just find those messages that are ready to send - and post those messages to an SNS topic and have a different lambda function that takes care of the actual processing (sending) of those messages.

Comment: E.J. Brennan, Thanks for your replay , current i am using dynamo db for this and continuing my work, but my ultimate aim is to avoid DB, So i am looking for any queue is there to hold my message until time comes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CloudWatch scheduled events for this. It allows you to specify cron expression. The event itself can trigger your lambda that then checks any preconditions you might have and then sends notification via SNS or some other way.